# Golang - Sorting on fan in

Tags: sorting, for-loop, go, concurrency, channel

I am randomly generating a bunch of log messages, and after they have been generated, I need to sort them by timestamp before writing them to the logs. I'm utilising the `sort.Interface` aspect of the `sort` library so I can sort based on my timestamp. I'm using a fan-in concurrency design, so my sorting function aggregates all the log messages from the goroutines, then sorts them.

Here is my code:

```
type CommonLogFormat struct {
    HostIP         string
    UserIdent      string
    User           string
    Timestamp      string
    Request        string
    HttpStatusCode int
    Size           int
}

type Logs struct {
    Messages []*CommonLogFormat
}

func sortByTimestamp(ch chan <- *CommonLogFormat) *Logs {
    logs := &Logs{Messages: make([]*CommonLogFormat, 1)}

    for i := range ch {
        logs.Messages = append(logs.Messages, <- i)
    }

    sort.Sort(logs)

    return logs
}

func (l Logs) Len() int {
    return len(l.Messages)
}

func (l Logs) Less(i,j int) bool {
    return l.Messages[i].Timestamp < l.Messages[j].Timestamp
}

func (l *Logs) Swap(i,j int) {
    l.Messages[i], l.Messages[j] = l.Messages[j], l.Messages[i]
}
```

However, when I go to receive a log message from the channel, I get this error:

```
invalid operation: <-i (receive from non-chan type *CommonLogFormat)
```

Why can't I receive a value from the channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory. Look at this:

```
for i := range ch {
    logs.Messages = append(logs.Messages, <- i)
}
```

`ch` is of type `chan <- *CommonLogFormat`. `ch` is a channel. The `for range` loop over the channel yields the values sent on the channel, which will be stored in the loop variable `i`. `i` is not a channel, but the values sent on the channel, so it will be of type `*CommonLogFormat`.

So no need, and you actually can't receive from it, it is already what you would want to receive from it. Simply append `i`:

```
for i := range ch {
    logs.Messages = append(logs.Messages, i)
}
```

The [Spec: For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) details what the loop variables are in case of `for range`:

```
Range expression                          1st value          2nd value

array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
```

The last line applies in case of ranging over a channel, and the first iteration value is the element.

> For channels, the iteration values produced are the successive values sent on the channel until the channel is [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close). If the channel is `nil`, the range expression blocks forever.

Comment: Ah, okay. That actually makes a lot of sense, thanks!